# QT creator custom project wizard how to call an executable when user click 'Next step'

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have read QT creator document [Adding JSON-Based Wizards](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html).

And I wonder **if there is any way to call an executable when user click 'Next step'** when using a custom project wizard.

[image]